# jquery linebreak when printing out

Tags: jquery, arrays

Here is the complete code (with some swedish comments..)
I try to make a "shoppingcart", what happens now is that all the saved values get printed out in a row and I would like a linebreak after each value.

```
<script>
$(function() {

    $(".p").click(function() {
      save($(this).text());
    });
});

function save(i){
    var foobar = new Array();


    var cock=unescape($.cookie('cockie'));


    if(cock != 'null')
        foobar = cock.split(';'); 


    foobar.push(i);


    $.cookie('cockie', escape(foobar.join(';')), {expires:1337});    


    $('#kundkorg').text("Kakan: "  + foobar.toString());
}

function clearCockie(){
    $.cookie("cockie", null);
    $('#cockieResult').text("");
}
```

Comment: Just removed my answer for now... you've missed `cookie` with `cockie` btw. You will have to create a data array and loop through printing out each value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add linebreaks in HTML with `<br/>`. So if you want to list every item of the array on an separate line in HTML, then you can do it like this:

```
var text = "";

for(n in foobar) {
    var item = foobar[n];

    text += item + "<br/>";
}

$("#kundkorg").html(text);
```

Comment: So should i replace my code with what you have written somewhere?

Comment: @user2915962 I deleted my answer after you clearified the question. Replace your line `$('#kundkorg').text("Kakan: "  + foobar.toString());` with the above.